# Draw a closed circle with LineRenderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;

    public bool circle = true;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float xradius = 15;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float yradius = 15;
    LineRenderer line;

    public float drawSpeed = 0.3f;

    void Start()
    {
        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.positionCount = (segments + 1);
        line.useWorldSpace = false;

        StartCoroutine(CreatePoints());
    }

    IEnumerator CreatePoints()
    {
        if (circle == true)
            yradius = xradius;

        float x;
        float z;

        float change = 2 * (float)Math.PI / segments;
        float angle = change;

        x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xradius;
        line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, 0));

        for (int i = 1; i < (segments); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * yradius;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(drawSpeed);
            line.SetPosition((int)i, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, z));

            angle += change;
        }
    }
}
```

When running the game I want it will start with one line at index 0 drawn already from the center of the circle. So I added this two lines before the loop:

```
x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xradius;
line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, 0));
```

Before adding this two lines the for loop was:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
```

But now I want to start the loop from index 1 so I tried:

```
for (int i = 1; i < (segments); i++)
```

But it's not making a complete round:

[image: Circle]

The circle drawing is moving in the clockwise direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You're not starting at 0

```
float angle = change; //change is > 0
```

I'll assume `change` is 10 degrees for the purposes of explanation.

Because of this, your first segment goes from the center, to a point 10 degrees around the circle.

You should do it like this:

```
    float angle = 0;

    x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * xradius;
    line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(x, 0.5f, 0));
```