# Unity3D- Is it possible to draw a circle / ellipse based on two vertices using a linerenderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to ask if it is possible to generate and draw a circle or ellipse using a linerenderer based on two points in the scene. Specifically, these are the vertices of the mesh. For example, I would like to draw a circle / ellipse around the neck of a given humanoid.

I need something like this:

[image: I need something like this]

I need this circle to enlarge and shrink based on the properties of the blendshapes. If I widen the neck with blendshape, I need this circle to enlarge as well. I can draw this circle by finding the id of all the vertices around the neck and entering these vertices into the LineRenderer. But it's a very impractical way that I don't want to use. So I would like to ask if it is possible to draw such a circle that would be connected only to two points and not to all / many.
I will be very grateful for any advice.

EDIT:
I was hoping that it would be enough to connect 4 vertices in the worldspace using LineRenderer, where I would get a drawn square. And I was hoping that some rounding would be used on the edges of this square to create an ellipse or circle. For a better idea, I also added a picture to describe what I thought would be enough to use.

[image: My idea was like this:]

Comment: You need at least three non-colinear points to draw a circle in 3D. Or, a center, radius and a normal vector. In any case, two points isn't enough information.

Comment: It may make more sense to create a new model that is the circle and make it a child of the neck, or add it to the neck's material so that the circle is literally drawn on the model rather than requiring separate geometry.

Comment: @3Dave Using three points would also be a great option for me. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to draw a circle with fewer vertices for a given mesh. I entered all the vertices on the neck there and I managed to draw the circle but it is a very impractical way. Please could you hint me a little as possible draw circle using three vertices?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have simply a center + radius and maybe only a setting for how many vertices to use (e.g. like min 3, max 32)

Comment: @derHugo I just have to have this circle tied exactly to the vertices of the neck mesh because when I change the dimensions of the neck using blendshapes, I want this circle to change as well. I did this by linking  all the neck vertices with lineRenderer but it's very impractical.

Comment: You can't draw it using only three vertices; you need three points in order to calculate the rest. For drawing a circle in general, this page has a decent explanation: https://www.loekvandenouweland.com/content/use-linerenderer-in-unity-to-draw-a-circle.html That example doesn't worry about having three points since it just draws the circle in the X/Z plane, which may be sufficient for your purposes. The tricky part is going to be finding your radius.

Comment: Another option would be to draw a textured quad (with a square texture that is just a circle on a transparent background), centered between your `VertexA` and `VertexB`. That's how we used to emulate 3D in (ugh) Flash. It works, but you're trading vertex shader time for pixel shader time, which is never a good idea for performance.

Comment: @3Dave Hi, Thank you for your answers and suggestions. So it will not be as easy as I expected the floods. I was hoping that it would be enough to connect 4 vertices in the worldspace using LineRenderer, where I would get a drawn square. And I was hoping that some rounding would be used on the edges of this square to create an ellipse or circle. For a better idea, I also added a picture to describe what I thought would be enough to use. So it will not work this way and I will have to use some of the methods you have suggested. Thank you very much again for your advice.

Comment: @Domino19 If you've got four points, just draw a quad with a texture. The texture is a picture of a circle (or whatever other shape you want).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705075/draw-a-closed-circle-with-linerenderer?rq=1

Comment: @3Dave Hi, thanks for your answers. In the end, I solved it by taking two opposite points. He calculated the center of the distance between them. Then I made a circle with the calculated radius and on this circle I created a lot of Vectors in the cycle. I then connected these vectors using a linerenderer and had a circle.